# Google Form reply to form respondents from a @domain email

Tags: google-forms

I'm using Google Forms to create a survey but the auto response email has my personal email account in it. How can I change it so the **from:** is, for instance `company@company.com` instead of `company@gmail.com`?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: [How to Send Google Forms Email Notifications from Another Email Address (Alias)](https://digitalinspiration.com/change-sender-email-7275)

Or, if you are using G-Suite, you can (and probably should, anyway) move the forms to that account, and that should work out of the box.

Other than those options, I doubt you can do this without some script. Search for google forms script email reply. I can recommend Ben Collins' app script course if you are interested in this route: [How to reply to Google Forms survey responses quickly with Sheets & Apps Script](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-forms-survey-tool/). In fact, I am doing exactly this, and it works like a charm (provided you are okay with writing script).